# Protractor and Angular: How to test two pages in an app, one after the other?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, protractor

I would like to run Protractor tests on two separate pages in my Angular app: `/dashboard` and `/articles`.

The complication is that I have to log in to the app manually.

Currently I have this setup:

```
var LoginPage = function() {
  ptor = protractor.getInstance();
  this.login = function(url) {
    ptor.get(url);
    ptor.findElement(protractor.By.model('email')).sendKeys(config.LOGIN_EMAIL);
    ptor.findElement(protractor.By.model('password')).sendKeys(config.LOGIN_PASS);
    ptor.findElement(protractor.By.tagName('button')).click();
  };
};

describe('The dashboard', function() {
  console.log('logging in');
  var loginPage = new LoginPage();
  loginPage.login(config.DASHBOARD_URL);
  console.log('logged in');
  it('has a heading', function() {
    console.log('testing dashboard 1');
    heading = ptor.findElement(protractor.By.tagName('h1'));
    expect(heading.getText()).toEqual(config.DASHBOARD_HEADING);
  });
});

describe('The article widget', function() {
  console.log('logging in');
  var loginPage = new LoginPage();
  loginPage.login(config.ARTICLE_URL);
  console.log('logged in');
  it('has a heading', function() {
    console.log('testing article 1');
    heading = ptor.findElement(protractor.By.tagName('h1'));
    expect(heading.getText()).toEqual(config.ARTICLES_HEADING);
  });
});
```

This gives me the following output:

```
Selenium standalone server started at http://192.168.2.9:56791/wd/hub
logging in
LoginPage
logged in
logging in
LoginPage
logged in
testing dashboard 1
Ftesting article 1
```

It looks as though both the `describe` sections are kicking off in parallel. How can I force the following sequence of events, while still structuring the code in a sensible way?

1. Load dashboard page
2. Log in
3. Run dashboard tests
4. Load article page (Assume we are already logged in)
5. Run article tests

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
describe('my app', function(){
    beforeEach(function(){
        login()...
    })
    describe('dashboard');
    describe('the article widget')
});
```

Comment: Yup! Putting stuff inside `describe` but outside of an `it` block or `beforeEach` block is a cause of odd issues with Jasmine tests, since things get initialized in funny places.

Comment: What if you want to call login() only once? Is there something like beforeEach() but executes once and will still be queued in the control flow? It can't be inside it() nor beforeEach(), but if it's just inside describe(), it doesn't work.

Comment: @supertonsky, im not sure I follow, are you asking if there's a one time before setup? look up jasmine beforeAll. https://github.com/nonplus/jasmine-beforeAll

Comment: @user2167582 That worked. Just recently switched to Jasmine 2

Answer (score 9):

You can move the login to another file.

Then, in your protractor configuration file do this:

```
exports.config = {
  specs: [
    'spec/login.js',
    'spec/dashboard_test.js',
    'spec/article_test.js'
  ],
  ...
};
```

Login will run before the other tests

Comment: perfect and simple solution

Comment: Important to note that this will fail if you want to clean-up cookies and/or local storage after some of your tests in order to have a clean state for each test; therefore having you lose login data if this is in some way stored with a token/key on client-side. I'd rather call the login in every test that needs it, within its beforeEach. If in the future you add a test that requires you to be logged out, this will also fail if you don't add it before the login spec.

Comment: unless you realize your app complexity grow out to authentication, and login provides userbase value that needs to be thoroughly tested

Answer (score 7):

The [Protractor documentation](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/faq.md#how-do-i-deal-with-my-log-in-page) recommends

> put your log-in code into an `onPrepare` function, which will be run once before any of your tests.

For example in your `protractor.conf`

```
onPrepare: function() {
    browser.driver.get('http://localhost/login.html');

    browser.driver.findElement(by.id('username')).sendKeys('Jane');
    browser.driver.findElement(by.id('password')).sendKeys('1234');
    browser.driver.findElement(by.id('clickme')).click();

    // Login takes some time, so wait until it's done.
    // For the test app's login, we know it's done when it redirects to
    // index.html.
    return browser.driver.wait(function() {
       return browser.driver.getCurrentUrl().then(function(url) {
          return /index/.test(url);
       });
    }, 10000);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I had a similar issue with my e2e protractor tests. Describe blocks were being executed in parallel, causing my tests to fail.

My code before the fix was something like:

```
describe('test1', function() {
  it('do foo1', function() {..});
  describe('do test1', function() {..});
});
describe('test2', function() {
  it('do foo2', function() {..});
  describe('do test2', function() {..});
});
```

Both the describe blocks were being executed in parallel causing my tests to fail. The fix was to enclose the it blocks in describe blocks.

Code after the fix:

```
describe('test1', function() {
  describe('foo1', function() {
    it('do foo1', function() {..});  
  });
  describe('do test1', function() {..});
});
describe('test2', function() {
  describe('foo2', function() {
    it('do foo2', function() {..});  
  });
  describe('do test2', function() {..});
});
```

Link to a similar issue on protractor github: https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/592